# Changing function names within a loop

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to neaten up some javascript with a loop - but am unsure of my syntax for changing variable names and function names within the loop. Just adapting things that have worked in the past, but perhaps not understanding it quite like I should?

This is what I have so far:

```
var sliderstorage=0;

for (var l = 0; l < ul.children.length; l++)
    {
    var Q = l+1;
    var Num = Q.toString();
    var string = "img" + Num;
    var change = string + "changeftot";

    var [string] = document.getElementById("[string]");
    console.log([string]);

    [string].addEventListener("click",[change]);


        function [change](e)
        {
            sliderstorage = e.target.value;
            console.log(sliderstorage);
            document.form1.Q11.value = sliderstorage;
        }
    };
```

And this is what I'm trying to achieve (this code def works):

I have added the html to make it clearer.

```
<div id="foo" class="block__list block__list_words" style="height: 100%">

<!--Add images here (change id and value)-->

     <div id="1"><input type="image"  id="img1" value="1" src="<#ImageFolder>\Q8_1.jpg"><br><br></div>

     <div id="2"><input type="image"  id="img2" value="2" src="<#ImageFolder>\Q8_2.jpg"><br><br></div>

    <div id="3"><input type="image"  id="img3" value="3" src="<#ImageFolder>\Q8_3.jpg"><br><br></div>

    <div id="4"><input type="image" id="img4" value="4" src="<#ImageFolder>\Q8_4.jpg"><br><br></div>        
</div>


<script>
// Enable to randomise, comment out to always show in same order

var ul = document.getElementById("foo");
for (var i = ul.children.length; i >= 0; i--)
ul.appendChild(ul.children[Math.random() * i | 0]);

//this is where the code I'm trying to neaten up starts:

var img1 = document.getElementById("img1");
var img2 = document.getElementById("img2");
var img3 = document.getElementById("img3");
var img4 = document.getElementById("img4");

var sliderstorage=0;

img1.addEventListener("click",img1changeftot);
img2.addEventListener("click",img2changeftot);
img3.addEventListener("click",img3changeftot);
img4.addEventListener("click",img4changeftot);

    function img1changeftot(e)
    {
        sliderstorage = e.target.value;
        console.log(sliderstorage);
                 document.form1.Q11.value = sliderstorage;
    }

    function img2changeftot(e)
    {
        sliderstorage = e.target.value;
        console.log(sliderstorage);
                document.form1.Q11.value = sliderstorage;
    }

    function img3changeftot(e)
    {
        sliderstorage = e.target.value;
        console.log(sliderstorage);
                document.form1.Q11.value = sliderstorage;
    }

    function img4changeftot(e)
    {
        sliderstorage = e.target.value;
        console.log(sliderstorage);
                document.form1.Q11.value = sliderstorage;
    }
```

Any help and input, greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: your functions do the same thing just for different images... why do you need multiple functions? Can't you just use one?

Comment: it's a bit unclear what you're doing in your code actually. is that supposed to be pseudocode?

Comment: I have four images (but want to make it so it doesn't matter how many images there are). 

The aim is to choose the best image. When clicking on the chosen image, the image value (1,2,3 or 4) is written to the form (and the page automatically moves to the next question).

The 'And this is what I'm trying to achieve' section shows the working code I currently have. 
It works. It's active. But I want to neaten it up and make it so that every time I add or a remove an image the code doesn't need to be changed.

Does that make sense? :)

Answer (score 3):

Why not do like this :

```
document.getElementById("foo").addEventListener("click", function(e){
   if(e.target.type=="image") document.form1.Q11.value = e.target.value;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add an event listener to a type of item like below. In your case get all the inputs on the page. Then check if that input type is image, if it is add the event listener to it.

```
var sliderstorage = 0

//create your function outside of the loop 
//so its not recreated in each iteration of the loop
function changeftot(e) {
    sliderstorage = e.target.value;
    console.log(sliderstorage);
    document.form1.Q11.value = sliderstorage;
}

var inputs =document.getElementById('foo').getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'image') {
        inputs[i].addEventListener('click', changeftot)
    }
};
```

Comment: Hey, I've added the html to make it clearer. ul is a var name. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are other images on the page. Which is why I've been referring to children of the div 'foo' in order to get these particular images.

Comment: updated to only add eventlistener to children of foo